# How does template argument shadowing work in VS2005?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-studio-2005

In GCC this code won't compile, because T gets shadowed, however in VS2005 it compiles with no warnings, so what are the assumptions VS compiler is making?

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
    template<typename T>
    void Bar(const T& bar)
    {
      ...
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get under gcc?

Comment: something like "T is shadowing class scope T"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the right answer after 3 months of searching :) It's in `14.6.1/4` of the Standard:

> A template-parameter shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes). A template-parameter shall not have the same name as the template name.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T, int i> class Y {
>     int T;
>     // error: template-parameter redeclared
>     void f() {
>         char T;
>         // error: template-parameter redeclared
>     }
> };
>
> template<class X> class X; // error: template-parameter redeclared
> ```

If the Microsoft compiler let it compile without errors or even warnings, it is not conforming. I don't know what could drive it to allow it without moaning. You could try to high warning levels.