# What's the point of "typedef sometype sometype"?

Tags: c++, typedef

Lately I've run into the following construction in the code:

```
typedef sometype sometype;
```

Pay attention please that "sometype" stands for absolutely the same type without any additions like "struct" etc.

I wonder what it can be useful for?

UPD: This works only for user defined types.

UPD2: The actual code was in a template context like this:

```
template <class T>
struct E
{
   typedef T T;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it didn't say: `typedef struct sometype sometype;`?

Comment: so a concrete example would be `typedef char char` ?

Comment: I wondered about the sample code, did not believe that it can be compiled. Tested. It can: `struct A { int x; }; int main(){ typedef A A; A a; return 0; }`

Comment: I can see NO functional benefit to that code. Perhaps it's a typo in the original code.

Comment: @SiegeX: It does not work on basic types. g++: error: multiple types in one declaration; error: declaration does not declare anything

Comment: `typedef sometype sometype;` is invalid C, I doubt you saw that in a standard-compliant, or even "regular", code.

Comment: @Alok: well actually it was C++ code, I assumed it to be the same in C

Comment: Since you’re talking about concrete types, why not give a *concrete* example, copied directly from the offending source without any editing?

Comment: @Konrad: I don't have that source at hand right now, but it was equivalent to the following: template<class T> class E { typedef T T; };

Comment: @Notinlist: Thanks for the correction! Indeed, this works only for UDTs

Comment: @Alex: *now* we’re getting somewhere!

Comment: @Alex: Please update the question with the information you gave to Konrad, it's important for understanding the question.

Comment: It works fine for basic types. You just have to declare an identifier. `int` isn't one. Try `typedef int foo; int main() { typedef foo foo; }` and see it working fine.

Comment: The template parameter is not accessible as `E::T` from outside as a type expression without typedef. That typedef causes an error on Linux G++ (`declaration of ‘typedef T E<T>::T’ shadows template parm class T`). We used to do that like `template<typename SomeRole_> struct E { typedef SomeRole_ SomeRole; };`, where SomeRole is not just a `T` but the role of that parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about to make Template parameters visible to outside entities?

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar
{
    typedef Foo Foo;
};

int main()
{
    Bar<int>::Foo foo = 4;
}
```

Note: this is actually not allowed in standard C++, but is specific to MSVC.  See comments.

Comment: Pretty sure it works in some compilers, so if the OP has seen this code around, this might be why, so it's still a valid answer to his question.

Comment: @Niel: Because if I delete it, some other smart fellow will think of the same thing and post it again.  Sometimes it's worth knowing what the wrong answer is.

Comment: It works in MSVC, but it's illegal C++. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486508/how-does-template-argument-shadowing-work-in-vs2005

Comment: @Niel: Aaaaaand because sometimes a wrong answer is the right answer?  *shrug*

Comment: G++: ``error: declaration of `typedef Foo Bar<Foo>::Foo’ shadows template parm `class Foo’ ``. So +1 from me with the reasoning of @KazDragon

Answer (score 7):

Given your additional information about templates, we can now answer.

The use-case is when you want to specialize on the type of a template. One typical example is the following:

```
template <typename T>
struct nonconst {
    typedef T t;
};

template <typename T>
struct nonconst<T const> {
    typedef T t;
};
```

This effectively allows you to remove the `const` qualifier from *any* type:

```
nonconst<int>::t x;
nonconst<int const>::t y;
assert(typeid(x) == typeid(int));
assert(typeid(y) == typeid(int));
```

There are many similar use-cases, e.g. to add (or remove) the pointer qualifier from a type, provide defaults and specializations for certain types, etc.

However, **notice the different casing** of the type names! <del>Equal types in `typedef T T` are illegal C++.</del>[I stand corrected: §7.1.3.2] Furthermore, the de-fact naming standard (cemented by its use in Boost libraries) is to call the type name alias `type`, e.g.:

```
typedef T type;
```

Comment: "Equal types in typedef T T are illegal " - this is incorrect. See 7.1.3.2 in the C++'03 Standard.

Comment: @Alex: I wasn’t aware of that. However, `g++` 4.4.2 (`-pedantic`) bails out when I use identical casing in the above code. So is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Sorry, I think the gotcha may be in the "non-class scope" remark. Comeau Online also doesn't compile this, but VC2008 does. I couldn't find the place in the standard that would explicitly disallow it (anyone?), so it may be implementation-defined.

Comment: @Alex, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486508/how-does-template-argument-shadowing-work-in-vs2005

Comment: Additionally, a member declaration is forbidden to introduce a name into a class scope that changes the result of lookup for a use of that name during completion of the class' scope. Having placed `typedef foo foo;` as a member declaration, however, does exactly that (it makes use of `foo`, but also declares a new name `foo`). See 3.3.6/1 bullet 2.

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks for the info! So this is just MSVC being non-conformant and someone taking advantage of it...

Answer (score 6):

In C++, you can put a typedef in a namespace or class, and then refer to it relative to that namespace or class, which can be useful if the real type might change in the future.

e.g.

```
class IntHolder
{
    public:
        typedef int int;
        IntHolder::int i;
};
...
IntHolder foo;
IntHolder::int i = foo.i;
```

(NB: I haven't checked that's quite the right syntax - but hopefully you get the idea)

If at some future point you actually want to hold `long` in `IntHolder` you only need to change the `IntHolder` code.

Now, normally you name the type differently, but maybe you can do as above?

Comment: Honorary +1 for a decent use scenario. I can see this easily happening for types less built-in than `int`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to compile any more than all the other answers suggesting this (with GCC and Comeau). - If the class is supposed to have only one typedef, just use `typedef X type;`, so people wouldn't have to guess each time. I mean, `IntHolder::int` would turn out to be `long`? Why call it **int** then and not `IntHolder::type`?

Comment: I didn't try it - and I'm glad I didn't because I would have hit gcc refusing it - whereas the OP's compiler (VS) managed to compile the template version.

Comment: As for the naming - it was a micro, non-compiled example. I hoped to get the idea across - and obviously the typedef had to be in that form to match the OP's question!

Answer (score 6):

I have a theory. It could be a result of some refactorings. For example a templated type become not templated.

```
typedef SomeCleverTemplate<Rocket> SuperThing;
```

Then they deleted the template, beacuse there were no other usage of it in the code, and for just to be safe they replaced every `SomeCleverTemplate<Rocket>` to `SuperThing`.

```
typedef SuperThing SuperThing;
```

Does it make sense in the real context?

Comment: Honorary +1 for "real context of too much automation". Sorry it's not a real +1, I'm out for the next 12 hours.

Answer (score 1):

As it as already been mentioned, it works especially well within a template:

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar
{
  typedef Foo Foo;
};
```

But it can also be combined with template specialization:

```
template <class Foo>
struct Bar<Foo*>
{
  typedef Foo Foo;
};
```

Now, I can do:

```
Bar<int>::Foo i = 0;
Bar<int*>::Foo j = i;
```

`Bar` thus effectively behaves as a kind of type wrapper, which may be important for its interface (if there is a `bool equals(Foo i) const` for example).

Usually the name elected has some meaning `value_type` for example...

Answer (score 0):

New idea! Certain clubs of programming like extensive usage of typedefs...

**zoo/animals/types.h**:

```
namespace zoo
{
    namespace animals
    {
        typedef size_t Count;
        // ...
    } // namespace animals
} // namespace zoo
```

**zoo/animals/zebra.h**:

```
#include "zoo/animals/types.h"

namespace zoo
{
    namespace animals
    {
        class Zebra {
        public:
            typedef Count Count;
            Count getLegCount() const;
            // ...
        }; // class Zebra
    } // namespace animals
} // namespace zoo
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "zoo/animals/zebra.h"

int main()
{
    typedef zoo::animals::Zebra Zebra;
    Zebra z;
    Zebra::Count n = z.getLegCount();
    // Not as zoo::animals::Count
    // No using namespace zoo::animals required,
    // we are using just one item from there, the Zebra.
    // Definition of Zebra::Count may change, your usage remains robust.
    return 0;
}
```

I just have a similar situation at my workplace. The translation of it may be a little bit silly, but I wanted to present it in a hurry.